# Задаю переменной значение 2 а компилятор выдает 49 C# в чем ошибка?

Tags: c#

Всем добрый день,
Учу C# и пытаюсь понять в чем ошибка.

```
namespace OWKiller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int processnum = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("CSGO #1 Overwatch #2");
            Console.WriteLine(processnum);
            processnum = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(processnum);
            Console.ReadKey();

            //            { 
            //                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Overwatch"))
            //            {
            ///                process.Kill();
            //            }
            //            }
            //        }
        }
    }
}
```

Если я пишу в консоли 1 то компилятор показывает что я ввел 49 а если 2 то компилятор показывает 50,с чем это связано? почему вместо 1 и 2 он показывает 49 и 50?

Comment: код введенного символа

Comment: @Grundy поподробнее можно? вы о кодировке?

Comment: c# воспринимает ввод от консоли как тип данных string. И выводит вам код символа из таблицы ASCII(или аналога). Что бы получить тип данных int сделайте конвертацию типа данных

Answer (score 7):

[Console.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) возвращает число.

Чтобы получить введенный символ в виде char, можно воспользоваться методом [`Convert.ToChar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToChar_System_Int32_)

```
ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

Comment: Он вроде пытаеться число получить. 
`ch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());`

Comment: @HegoJune, да именно это, поэтому переменная у меня названа не `processnum` как у автора вопроса, а `ch`. У тебя пропущен вызов `ToChar`. `Console.Read` и так возвращает `Int32` - поэтому нет смысла применять `Convert.ToInt32` результат будет эквивалентен `Console.Read()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь @Grundy

Answer (score 0):

Добился результата следующим кодом.

```
namespace OWKiller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int processnum = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Overwatch #1 CSGO #2");
            Console.WriteLine(processnum);

            bool checked1 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out processnum);
            if (checked1) {
                Console.WriteLine(processnum);
            }


                       if (processnum == 1)
                       { 

                                { 
                                       foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Overwatch"))
                                   {
                                   Console.WriteLine("Crashing Overwatch...");

                                       process.Kill();
                                  }
                                   }
                               }

                       else
                       {
                           foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo"))
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine("Crashing CSGO");
                               process.Kill();
                           }
                       }


        }
    }
}
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Обрати внимание, что `char` - Это **не** число. И если ты хочешь полученный символ `1` использовать в качестве цифры - нужно вызывать дополнительно `Convert.ToInt32` например

Comment: @Grundy уже понял,спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
        int processnum = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("CSGO #1 Overwatch #2");
        Console.WriteLine(processnum);
        // сделайте так чтобы проверить правильно ли вел пользователь значение
        bool isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out processnum );
        if(isNumber){
              Console.WriteLine(processnum);
        }            

        Console.ReadKey();
```